# Angular: Must @Input() be above @ViewChild? And why?

Tags: angular

I have a component ImageUploaderComponent with an @Input value and an @ViewChild value.

```
export class ImageUploaderComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() canvasheight: number;
  @ViewChild('cropper', undefined)
  ...
}
```

The component works fine if the @Input() line is before the @ViewChild(...) line, but doesn't work if they are reversed. I think it may have to do with @ViewChild not taking a semi-colon, that causes an error.

EDIT:
Well, this was a syntax mistake. You don't have to have @Input() above @ViewChild, contrary to what the question is suggesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Input and ViewChild decorator do not have a specific declaration order.

Do note that the variables are only available in ngOnInit(), not before (say in the constructor).

What even is the 'undefined' in your @ViewChild declaration? Proper declaration is:

```
@ViewChild(ChildDirective) child: ChildDirective;
```

or

```
@ViewChild('reference') child: ChildDirective;
```

Comment: How embarrassing, it should be @ViewChild('cropper', undefined) cropper: ImageCropperComponent;  When I was reversing the lines I wasn't moving the 'cropper: ImageCropperComponent'.